# Selecting raw data values with JS/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select the value from some raw data with jquery.
I tried something like this 
`var id = $("body").data("id");`

The raw data looks something like this 
`{"photo":{"id":85456501,"user_id":601182}}`

Any ideas?

Comment: if you have `var data= {"photo":{"id":85456501,"user_id":601182}}` then you need to use `data.photo.id` to get the id value. Where is the object located? Is it a data attribute on the body element? If not your selector will return nothing.

Comment: For simplicity reasons the raw data located in the body and it appears exactly like that in plaintext.

Comment: then to get the id value you need to start at the key `photo` you can't skip over keys.

Comment: It'd be simpler to use `data-id` and `data-userid`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the raw data string inside this body element:

```
var rawData = $("body").text();
```

Every Javascript object is also a JSON String, so you can parse it like JSON.

```
var data = JSON.parse(rawData);
```

Now you can get the ID like this:

```
var id = data.photo.id
var userid = data.photo.user_id
```

Comment: Probably not great to name a variable `object`... :)

Comment: true story that's not so great, i fixed it, thank you ;)

Comment: Perfect that's exactly what I needed. Also now I know what I can do with JSON (haven't every used it, or knew what it was/could do). @Matthias